# how to swap two dropdownlists with one button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do you change the values of two dropdownlists. what mean is to swap the values of each other dropdownlists with a button or a arrow icon like normal ddls.

Comment: What have you tried doing so far? Swapping values in a dropdown list is the same concept of swapping values in an array.

Comment: like unit converter which converts to cm to m but then i want o press the button and have m to cm displayed so swap dropdownlist with dropdownlist 2 and display the conversion

Comment: Now I'm confused, do you want to swap the `value`'s in a dropdown list of the words inside the text of them? You are going to need to give an example with code.

Comment: yes i want to convert the values inside the ddl 1 and ddl 2 exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this as follows:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="mySelect1" size="5" multiple style="width:200px">
                <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td valign="center">
            <button id="toRight">►</button><br/>
            <button id="toLeft">◄</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="mySelect2" size="5" multiple style="width:200px">
                <option value="opt4">Option 4</option>
                <option value="opt5">Option 5</option>
                <option value="opt6">Option 6</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript (pure)**

```
function moveOptionsTo(index) {
    var target = document.getElementById('mySelect' + index);
    var options = document.getElementById('mySelect' + (3-index)).options;
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) {
            target.appendChild(options[i]);
            i = i - 1;
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById('toRight').onclick = function() {
    moveOptionsTo(2);
};
document.getElementById('toLeft').onclick = function() {
    moveOptionsTo(1);
};
document.getElementById('mySelect1').ondblclick = function() {
    moveOptionsTo(2);
};
document.getElementById('mySelect2').ondblclick = function() {
    moveOptionsTo(1);
};
```

**Alternative: Javascript with `jQuery`**

```
function moveOptionsTo(index) {
    $('#mySelect' + (3-index) + ' option:selected').appendTo('#mySelect' + index);
}
$('#toRight').click(function() {
    moveOptionsTo(2);
});
$('#toLeft').click(function() {
    moveOptionsTo(1);
});
$('#mySelect1').dblclick(function() {
    moveOptionsTo(2);
});
$('#mySelect2').dblclick(function() {
    moveOptionsTo(1);
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vzvt8jrm/) using the above code. This allows multi-select and double-click on items or button to move.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<label>Browser Select 1</label>
  <select class="browser-default" id="drop1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>

<label>Browser Select 2</label>
  <select class="browser-default" id="drop2">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 4</option>
    <option value="2">Option 5</option>
    <option value="3">Option 6</option>
  </select>

<button id="switch">switch</button>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('#switch').click(function(){
    var options1 = $('#drop1').html();
    $('#drop1').html($('#drop2').html());
    $('#drop2').html(options1);
});
```

Plain javascript thanks to [Spencer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3149020/spencer-wieczorek):

```
document.getElementById("switch").onclick = function() {
    var drop1 = document.getElementById("drop1");
    var drop2 = document.getElementById("drop2");
    var tempHTML = drop1.innerHTML;

    drop1.innerHTML = drop2.innerHTML;
    drop2.innerHTML = tempHTML;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5g550tqq/3/

Comment: The OP isn't using jQuery.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek he might consider it now.

Comment: I would avoid giving solutions that use jQuery if they didn't include a `jquery` tag in the question. Or give a pure JS solution included.

Comment: yeah so how do I swap with pure javascript

Comment: @HaroonIqbal & Spencer: I tried it in plain JS but I really don't know how to implement `find` without jQuery

Comment: @Thomas [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/5g550tqq/2/). Note you can use a `document.querySelector()` to do that, but it's not needed.

Comment: @spencer is close but i want to display the value like option 1 and option 4 then u press swap and it displays option 4 and option 1 below and not use innerHTML

Comment: i improve the sentence above i want to swap the selected value of both ddl and display them in the ddl

Comment: @HaroonIqbal In that case you need to swap the `.selectedIndex` values as well. [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/5g550tqq/4/), is that what you want?

Comment: cool but how does it work without innerHTML ?

Comment: @HaroonIqbal Because you can set the selected item in a dropdown by using the `selectedIndex` property of the element. You don't need to modify the DOM.

Comment: any example without innerHTML

Comment: @HaroonIqbal Do you mean you want to only swap the two value elements and not swap the dropdowns? Or have the same functionally but without using `.innerHTML`? (*This is why it's a good idea to have an example result of what you want*)

Comment: yes how do i replace inner HTML

Comment: @HaroonIqbal Yes to which one?

Comment: so has the same functionality but without the .innerHTML

Comment: @HaroonIqbal Why so, is there a reason you can't use it? Any other way would be a good amount more complex and may not work in all cases.

Comment: i would like to know though if you have an answer please